# Why is the blank profile sentence not correct?

Tags: bug, profile-page, grammar

When a user has not chosen to provide profile details, the boilerplate text is:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

That reads poorly, as noted by [this answer on SE EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/4915) and some of the other answers to the question, [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)

There are alternative ways to word the sentence that would be better. Consider the following suggestions:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery.
>
> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about themselves.

Comment: What, precisely, is grammatically incorrect? "X keeps a Y about them" is perfectly good, if perhaps somewhat old-fashioned, English. (If they had said "about their person" it would perhaps be clearer, if still more archaic.)

Comment: It is not old-fashioned English. There isn't noun-verb agreement! X is singular, while Y is plural.

Comment: Grammar edit suggestions usually don't work, for two reasons: 1) They're incorrections rather than corrections, and 2) Now that Jeff is gone, there are many small esses to deal with pluralization bugs. Now this fits 1 well.

Comment: Ever heard of singular "they"? No offence, but you're clearly not showing enough effort to know this isn't wrong grammar.

Comment: @EllieKesselman: "an air of mystery" is **not** plural.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M What is an incorrection? Also, what does your second bullet point mean, "Now this fits 1 well"?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I know it isn't! I wasn't referring to an air of mystery. I am referring to "about them" or "about themselves". User is singular. Them or themselves is plural.

Comment: No, "them/themselves" is singular here. This is a natural way to indicate gender neutrality.

Comment: SE doesn't have its own grammar, separate from the rest of the world. EL&U SE uses correct English grammar. Meta SE should too.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Regardless of that, the sentence remains incorrect. Look at my third suggestion, where I suggested the grammatically incorrect plural but still corrected the other part of the sentence. I don't see any point in debating this in comments on the questions. I'd rather respond further to answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list)

Comment: @tchrist: That question says to open a new question for any additional bugs.

Comment: No offense, but I really don't see the issue here - i doubt that there will be riots in the streets over a dispute about grammar. *Having said that, if there are riots in the streets over a grammar dispute, I would like to see the footage of the grammar police with their exclamation battons charging.*

Comment: [MSO dup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291914/who-is-are-them), [MSE dup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253463/293416) and [ELU post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242773/is-the-use-of-them-right-here)

Comment: Grammar fights are awesomely funny!

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, there is an [ELU post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus). See the [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/4915).

Comment: @NathanTuggy It isn’t an additional bug: [this duplicate bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253463/293416) is specifically marked [tag:status-declined]. That’s why it’s a duplicate.

Comment: @EllieKesselman So it isn't grammatically incorrect. It *can* be used. IMO, you should provide the link to the ELU post here and should point out the critisism.

Comment: @EllieKesselman I meant that the link be provided in this post(your question) because most people don't see / click the link buried under a pile of comments. Also, comments are temporary.  You might also want to remove "_grammatically incorrect_" from this post as the sentence isn't grammatically incorrect .

Answer (score 16):

You appear to be objecting to two slightly unusual features of the sentence. The first is the use of "them" to refer to a singular individual, and the second is the omission of "-self". I don't know what else to tell you about the use of singular them; it's quite common, however awkward it may seem on general principles, so it must essentially be taken as the unfortunate wart on English that it is and accepted.

But even the objection to "them" instead of "themselves" is not really warranted. A sentence like "He wrapped his cloak about him" (with no one else around to refer to with "him") is not wrong: it is old-fashioned. (For example, the King James Version uses that general pattern in [II Sam 22:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ii+sam+22%3A12&version=KJV).) And that's exactly the same pattern being used here.

Comment: @EllieKesselman: "About" is being used in more of a location sense than an informational sense, which is really why I thought of that passage in the first place. The "air of mystery" is being kept *around* them, rather than keeping an air of mystery *regarding* their information.

Comment: Ok, i also thought it was grammaticaly incorrect : there is absolutely no way i can translate this in my own language and end up with something valid, i guess it's one of these poethic english formulations. Good to know, i upvote this considering it answered my question.

Comment: When the subject has a definite singular number assigned to it 'them' is never correct.  "Apparently, this user (insert name of single individual here) prefers to keep an air of mystery about them." cannot be made grammatically correct.  Only when a singular number is not definitively assigned to the subject is it appropriate to use they/them.  For instance, "Janice has something to say, let them speak." is wrong while "Whomsoever has something to say, let them speak." is correct.