# Will the old "about me" message be affected by these recent pronoun usage rules?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, tour

While browsing various Stack Exchange sites + the private one I am currently administrating where I work I see that many profiles still show the classic About me placeholder:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about **them**.

I could not help but link this placeholder to the never-ending discussions about pronoun usage and its enforcement by SE.

If I remove my About me text now I see another text:

> (Your about me is currently blank.)
>
> Click here to edit

So, clearly the initial placeholder is not used after a custom About me text is saved.

I am wondering if this placeholder text will be affected by all these pronoun usage related changes (SE missed a spot) or it is not linked to the newest rules (although it is the message someones sees in their profile).

**Question:** Will the old "about me" message be affected by these recent pronoun usage rules?

Comment: Related: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251810), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290842), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261359).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) says:

> **Be inclusive and respectful.**
>
> Prefer gender-neutral language when uncertain.

Since the system doesn't know the user's gender, it reverts to the gender-neutral 'them'.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t like being referred to as “them” then you can put this in your About Me:

> Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about [insert your pronoun here]

(Or, you know, change the entire message to pretty much anything else.)

The system does not know your pronouns (by design, to prevent people from abusing it I guess), so it uses [gender neutral *them*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336368/323179), as the CoC specifies.

Comment: You are right about customizing the message. My question is also a little bit of irony of the tremendous effort put by SE in relation to the pronoun usage.