# "this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them" - can this wording be changed?

Tags: discussion, security, privacy, metadata

I'm posting this question anonymously for obvious reasons.  It should be on meta, but I can't post there anonymously.  It would be great if someone would move it there.

The new head of the Department of Homeland Security has told the House Homeland Security Committee that he plans to make it mandatory for visitors to the US to disclose their social media accounts, including passwords.  He also plans to spend "weeks or months" vetting visitors.

https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/02/08/dhs_wants_enhanced_digital_vetting/

I'm planning to visit the US later this year, by which time this new process may be well underway.  I have a colourful collection of visas in my passport, so I'm taking this opportunity to scrub google clean of anything that may trigger the interest of a border agent.

That's how I noticed that one of the top results for my name is SuperUser telling the world "this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them".  Cute.  Unfortunately border agents have zero sense of humour, no conception of irony or wordplay, and little familiarity with the world of "hackers" beyond what Hollywood tells them.

Can this wording be changed to something more neutral and less inviting of a curious click please?  Perhaps "no profile information available".

Comment: I voted to migrate this, but why not just post anything there, so the default text is replaced?  Second thought, your question sort of suggests that you might be the kind of person Homeland Security should be looking at.  Is it really in the self-interest of Americans to tell you how to defeat the safeguards?

Comment: "The new head of the Department of Homeland Security", No, he is considering it.  It will be months from being implemented if that even happens.  It would only apply to people comming into the country on a long-term or permanent visas.  You shouldn't worry about a policy hat hasn't even be written yet...

Comment: You can fill your "about yourself" however you like which will show you your desired phrase instead of "air of mystry".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251810/the-site-should-not-make-speculative-statements-about-its-users

Comment: If only social media accounts need to be declared then the SE network is not a social network.

Answer (score 15):

I understand your concern and I sympathize with your worries. However, I don't think SE should remove all fun and wordplay just for cases like this, where the law is still just a suggestion raised and you yourself have the opportunity to change the text yourself.

If you are concerned about the default text, just change it to whatever you think is appropriate. No need for SE to change the text at all.

Answer (score 2):

This has been rendered obsolete with the launch of the [fully responsive profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370964/now-live-a-fully-responsive-profile), as the About Me section is now simply hidden when empty.